# How to make send message to particular URI after successfull webscoket connection?

Tags: go, websocket, ssl-certificate, client-server, gorilla

I have a secure websocket server running on localhost:443/server-demo ( jetty websocket server). 
Now I am writing a go client that can communicate with the websocket server. I am able to connect to the websocket server using right certificates. Here is the sample code.

```
package main
import (
    "crypto/tls"
    "crypto/x509"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
)
func main() {
    cert, err := tls.LoadX509KeyPair("nifi-1.10.0-bin/nifi-1.10.0/extras/gen-certs/certs/admin.pem", "nifi-1.10.0-bin/nifi-1.10.0/extras/gen-certs/certs/admin-key.pem")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("server: loadkeys: %s", err)
    }
    config := tls.Config{Certificates: []tls.Certificate{cert}, InsecureSkipVerify: true}
    conn, err := tls.Dial("tcp", "127.0.0.1:443", &config)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("client: dial: %s", err)
    }
    defer conn.Close()
    log.Println("client: connected to: ", conn.RemoteAddr())
    state := conn.ConnectionState() 
    for _, v := range state.PeerCertificates {
        fmt.Println(x509.MarshalPKIXPublicKey(v.PublicKey))
        fmt.Println(v.Subject)
    }
    log.Println("client: handshake: ", state.HandshakeComplete)
    log.Println("client: mutual: ", state.NegotiatedProtocolIsMutual)
    message := "Hello\n"
    n, err := io.WriteString(conn, message)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("client: write: %s", err)
    }
    log.Printf("client: wrote %q (%d bytes)", message, n)
    reply := make([]byte, 256)
    n, err = conn.Read(reply)
    log.Printf("client: read %q (%d bytes)", string(reply[:n]), n)
    log.Print("client: exiting")
}
```

The above code  throws this error:

```
 "HTTP/1.1 400 No URI\r\nContent-Type: text/html;charset=iso-8859-1\r\nContent-Length: 49\r\nConnection: close\r\nServer: Jetty(9.4.19.v20190610)\r\n\r\n<h1>Bad Message 400</h1><pre>reason: No URI</pre>" (188 bytes)
```

My question is after making the connection how can I send message to  particular URI? i.e I want to send a message to `wss://localhost:443/server-demo`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code in a question does not establish a WebSocket connection to the server.

To establish the WebSocket connection, the application must write a WebSocket handshake to `conn` and receive the handshake response.  See the [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455) for the details.

Most applications use a websocket package than handles all of these details. The [gorilla/websocket](https://godoc.org/github.com/gorilla/websocket) package is a popular choice.

This code should get you started with gorilla:

```
cert, err := tls.LoadX509KeyPair("nifi-1.10.0-bin/nifi-1.10.0/extras/gen-certs/certs/admin.pem", "nifi-1.10.0-bin/nifi-1.10.0/extras/gen-certs/certs/admin-key.pem")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("server: loadkeys: %s", err)
}
config := tls.Config{Certificates: []tls.Certificate{cert}, InsecureSkipVerify: true}
d := websocket.Dialer{
    TLSClientConfig: &config,
}
c, _, err := d.Dial("wss://localhost:443/server-demo", nil)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

defer c.Close()
// Use `c` to send and receive messages
```

Comment: it must be repeated ... `InsecureSkipVerify  true` disables tls checking so if you think your code is secure remove that attribute before rolling into production ... replace it with something like  `my_dialer.TLSConfig = &tls.Config{
                    RootCAs:      caCertPool,   
                    ServerName: domain_name,
                }`